# Querying for specific articles (via tag/category) in Pelican themes

Tags: python, jinja2, pelican

Is it possible to set query parameters via jinja in Pelican template files?

`index.html`

```
{% if articles %}
    {% for article in articles_page.object_list if article.category == 'article' %}        
        #stuff
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

This will return articles in the article category, but only if they happen to be in the articles already queried for. The desirable setup would be to grab x articles in y category (or with y tag) - is that possible?

Answer (score 7):

This code snippet works for me to bring back a list of all articles matching a tag:

```
 {% block content %}
 <ul>
 {% for article in articles if FAVORITES_TAG in article.tags %}
   {% if loop.index <= FAVORITES_COUNT %} 
     <li><a href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }}</a></li>
   {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

I set the FAVORITES_TAG and FAVORITES_COUNT variables in the config. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and found a solution

```html
{% if articles %}
    {% for article in articles_page.object_list if article.category.name == 'article' %}        
        #stuff
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```