# Pelican: Create Hyperlinked Metadata

Tags: python, pelican

I'm trying to develop an elegant way to create arbitrary metadata in a pelican template such that the result hyperlinks to existing pages. For example, if I have a category `goal` with a page `first-goal` that's structured like:

```
content
├── pages
│   ├── goal
│   │   ├── first-goal.md
```

I want to be able to do the following in an article metadata:

```
Title: First Article
Goal: first-goal
```

And then in a template, translate the `first-goal` from the `goal` metadata such that it is a link to that goal page, like:

```
{%- for goal in article.goal %}
    <a href="[link to goal page(s)]">goal</a>
{% endfor %}
```

---

A few thoughts I've had:

- Is there a good plugin to do something close to this that I could modify? I've looked at linker and interlinks from [pelican-plugins](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins) which seem close, but not quite
- I could modify FORMATTED_FIELDS to include `goal`, and manually add hyperlinks, then use `{filename}/pages/goal/first-goal.md` as a hyperlink in the `goal:` metadata. This seems redundant and doesn't use the existing structure at all.
- Manually create a mapping in a settings file that has something like a dict looking like `GOAL_LINKS = {'first_goal' : 'link-to-first-goal.html'}`, then call `GOAL_LINKS.first_goal` in the templates. Again, this solution is a little more manual than I'd like.

Has anyone done something similar or have any ideas on how to accomplish this in the general case, taking advantage of the existing metadata and category structure and reducing the need for manual mappings?

Answer (score 3):

I did something very similar yesterday. My site's structure looks something like this:

```
content
├── pages
│   ├── cars.md
│
├── cars
│   ├── car-page.md
```

I decided to use the slug to determine where to save articles. My config file contains these lines:

```
ARTICLE_URL = '{slug}.html'
ARTICLE_SAVE_AS = '{slug}.html'
```

and when I create a new file, I put the category and slug at the top of `car-page.md`, which will be used to tell Pelican to save the html file in the `cars` directory and to categorize it as such:

```
Title: My Car Page
Slug: cars/car-page
Category: cars
...
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22426348/5472966) which helped me figure out how to iterate through all articles in my car directory and used the `cars.md` file as a landing page for the topic. My version of the loop looks like this, in my `page.html` template file:

```
{% block content %}
    {{ page.content }}
    <ul>
    {% for article in articles if page.category == article.category %}
        <li><a href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }} - {{ article.locale_date }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

[Here](https://github.com/McGlothlin/pelican-site) is a link to my site's repo in case you would like to see all the pieces of the puzzle in action. I highly recommend going through another Pelican site or two (be it mine or someone else's) to see how things are done; it really helped me understand how things are put together and opened my mind to what's possible. Here's a good list of Pelican sites: https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/wiki/Powered-by-Pelican